# wait asynchronous events in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, asynchronous, async-await

Im new in Javascript so i need help!

I have this communictaion file:

```
var sDevices = {};
module.exports={
    initDevices: function(){
        client.findResources( )
        .catch( function( error ) {
            console.log( JSON.stringify( { assertion: "ok", arguments: [
                false, "Client: Starting device discovery failed: " +
                ( "" + error ) + "\n" + JSON.stringify( error, null, 4 )
            ] } ) );
        });
        client.on( "resourcefound",initThem);
    },
    getDevices:function(){
        return sDevices;
    }
}
```

with this linstener:

```
async function initThem(resource){
   await client.retrieve(resource);
    if( _.has(resource,'properties.n') === true ){
        _.unset(resource,'properties.n');
    }
   sDevices[resource.resourceTypes[0]]=resource;
}
```

and this is my application file:

```
function start(){
    communication.initDevices();
    var devices=communication.getDevices();
    console.log(devices);
}

start();
```

So the problem is the devices object in application js is empty because of the asynchronous call  of getDevices(). Can i use something to await the sDevices filled with all smart devices?

Comment: Learn to use promises

Comment: Where's the actual code that fills in a value for `sDevices`?  You can't "wait" for an asynchronous operation in Javascript.  Instead, you set up a callback or promise that will notify you when the async operation is done and you perform your work in that callback.

Comment: to store a value in sDevices i use the listener and this is the code: sDevices[resource.resourceTypes[0]]=resource;

Comment: @jfriend00 with `await` he can "wait" it is syntax sugar to promise resolution.

Comment: `await` doesn't change the fundamental process.  It's just syntax sugar.  Meanwhile, the rest of his code continues to run.  There's no real "waiting".  This is a classic async design issue.  The OP needs to learn how to design for async responses.  The language won't hide that fact.

Comment: In your `start` function, you're not waiting for anything. Also, when do you know that `findResources` has found all resources (and fired all `resourcefound` events that you want to wait for)?

Comment: u cant know when the findResources() has found all resources,when a resource has found, program runs the listener and the resource is added in the sDevices.

Comment: @jimloca: If you can't know when `findResources` has found all the resources, then you can't know when you can call `getDevices` to get all the devices.

Comment: I have a working solution for your [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153795/operator-for-objects-nodejsjavascript) (no loops) but you deleted the question. If you undelete it then I'll post an answer.